# $P(B)$ given $P(A\cup B)$ and $P(A'|B')$: Probability

Tags: probability

> Assume that $P(A\cup B) = 5/6$ and $P(A'|B') = 1/3.$ Determine $P(B).$

---

Would it be safe to assume that $P(A|B) = 1 - P(A'|B'),$ or is this assumption incorrect?

Comment: No, but you can safely assume that $P(A | B) = P(A) - P(A | \neg B)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write 
$$
P(A'\mid B')=\frac{P(A'\cap B')}{P(B')}
$$
in terms of only $P(A\cup B)$ and $P(B)$ using one of De Morgan's laws. Then solve for $P(B)$.

Comment: So using DeMorgan's law on P(A'∩B') would give the compliment of P(A∪B)?

Comment: @Kayseta: Exactly.